# CSS Images move up and down on browser resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to move into responsive web design and I'm having a bit of an issue with my CSS images moving up and down when the browser width changes. Right now I'm working on the nav bar and I'd simply like my menu buttons to stay at the same height within the nav bar as the browser resizes in width, until it at least hits the next @media query and pulls different CSS attributes.

CSS Code:

```
 html, body
{
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%
 }
ul {list-style-type: none; }
li {display: inline;}
#wrapper {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

    /* Large Resolutions Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
/* Main Navigation Styling */
#main_nav{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #1D5799;
}
li.hom a {
    margin-top: .5%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 349px;
    height: 188px;

    background-image: url('images/menu-desktop/logo-desk.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-indent:-9999999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li.ab a{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 20%;
    width: 157px;
    height: 38px;

    background-image: url('images/menu-desktop/about-desk.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-indent:-9999999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li.iss a{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 30%;
    width: 152px;
    height: 38px;

    background-image: url('images/menu-desktop/iss-desk.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-indent:-9999999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

li.new a{ 
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 40%;
    width: 133px;
    height: 38px;

    background-image: url('images/menu-desktop/news-desk.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-indent:-9999999px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.menu-main-menu-nav-container{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#mobile_logo{
    display:none;
}
/* Body Styling */
#main_content{overflow:auto;}

/*Foot Styling */
#f_container {
    position: relative;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #1D5799;
    z-index: 1;
}



}
```

Then here are a few images showing what I mean:

Full size, positioned correctly:
http://puu.sh/fX3BV/0551e774ce.jpg

Browser width decreased, the menu buttons start moving upwards:
http://puu.sh/fX3It/006ff219a5.jpg

The menu buttons will continue to move upwards until it hits the next media query and "resets" to that browser's resolution. I'd post a live link but it's still only a local build right now. If you'd prefer a OBS video to show the effect I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a more minimal example?

Comment: You mean a more minimal example of CSS code?

Comment: Exactly. The least code needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Okay not a problem, I cut out all the code except for the browser resolution that I'm working at by default, though it's an issue at every one.

Comment: make a jsfiddle example =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items are moving up due the % margin-top value you have put. try using px instead from margin-top. From my experience you only really need to use % values for horizontal positioning

Comment: It's looking like this is the issue. So it looks like for vertical positioning I'll stick to vertical px values and horizontal I'll stick to %.

Answer (score 1):

Go `position: absolute` and `top: 40px`(approximately), then use the `left` & `right` properties to set the px amounts for the rest of your nav buttons.